# Self-Deleting Model Object Django

Tags: django

How would you have a model object delete itself 60 seconds after it has been initialized? I know you could override the delete() method to have it sleep for 60 seconds before actually deleting the object. However, if I made a method call to delete() in a view. Wouldn't it just end up stalling the view for 60 seconds before continuing?

So how would I be able to do this without worrying about these stalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can start new thread, wait for 60 secs and delete the object. So view won't be blocked.

Another approach would be to use asynchronous task manager like [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) to start a new task to delete object after 60 secs.

Answer (score 3):

Put a 'to_be_deleted' booleanfield in the model, and set up a cron job to run every 60 seconds to delete all instances with the flag set.